# How to make my SELECT queries executed inside a for loop faster/more efficient?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, performance, select

I have the following code which is pretty straightforward but will be obviously and unacceptably slow if the map I'm iterating through has lots of entries.

```
public Map<String, String> getIdToEmailMapping(Connection conn, Map<String, String> map) {

    Map<String, String> id_email_map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        String sql = "SELECT EMAIL FROM DATA_VIEW WHERE URL=?";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {    
            stmt.setString(1, entry.getValue());    // set URL in sql statement
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String email = rs.getString("EMAIL");
                String id = entry.getKey();
                id_email_map.put(id, email);
            }
            rs.close();         
         }
         stmt.close();
     } catch (SQLException se) {
         se.printStackTrace();
     }

     return id_email_map;

}
```

I expect the map to have thousands of entries so this implementation is just bad... but I'm not sure if I can do it any other way. I tried searching for any SQL tricks for this kind of problem, but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you can do "Select EMAIL from DATA_VIEW WHERE URL in (id1, id2, id3 ....)" and do batches of say 100 or 1000 entries. Also, use the try-with-resource block to close your statements.

Comment: Assuming you're using oracle (like your tag) you could do this: insert the entire result into a temp table.  Do a count on the table.  Select groups of results by using ROWNUM and LIMIT to get certain results (e.g. ROWNUM > 500 LIMIT 500 to get results 501-1000).  Make sure you use consistent order by to avoid duplicates

Comment: I suggest stepping back to where these thousands of entries originate and looking for ways to make the whole thing run faster.  Usually it's a simple matter of joining tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
static void call(final Connection con) throws SQLException {
        Map<String, String> emailMap = new HashMap<>();
        emailMap.put("id1", "someVal");
        emailMap.put("id2", "someVal");
        emailMap.put("id3", "someVal");
        emailMap.put("id4", "someVal");

        String collect = emailMap.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));


        String query = " SELECT EMAIL FROM DATA_VIEW WHERE URL IN (" + collect + ")";


        try (Statement s = con.createStatement()) {

            ResultSet executeQuery = s.executeQuery(query);
            // do your result processing
        }

    }
```

Instead of querying all your urls separately, you can send one query for all your ids or urls. The query will look like this:

```
SELECT EMAIL FROM DATA_VIEW WHERE URL in (id2,id1,id4,id3)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked for me. Using the IN clause and doing batches of 1000 entries made it faster. I tried working with the IN operator before asking my question, but it didn't work then so I didn't think it would solve my problem. Turns out I just had to tweak my code and the query a bit more to meet the specific requirements of my program. Thanks!